# Why are settings.xml and pom.xml are not directing Maven to deploy to Artifactory?

Tags: maven, artifactory

I am trying to point Maven to a local Artifactory (OSS) repo (both on my Mac) so I can build code provided by a vendor. I have created an empty Maven local repo and virtual repo in Artifactory, and can use Generate Settings to create the snippets. My ID and encrypted password seem to be working OK in ~/.m2/settings.xml

I have updated the code's pom.xml file and that seems to be causing Maven to ***resolve*** from Artifactory.

No matter how I configure  in ~/.m2/settings.xml or in the master settings.xml or with -Dmaven.repo.local, Maven wants to ***deploy*** to a disk path to the local repo.

- If I specify a partial path, Maven says "Using local repository at " a path consisting of the code's home + the path I said.
- If I specify a path starting with a / (root), Maven says "Using local repository at /whatever"
- I want to specify "https://localhost/artifactory/reponame" so Maven will deploy there.  Artifactory generates snippets that contain that kind of URL. But since a URL doesn't start with a /, Maven insists on prepending the code home location to the URL, which of course is nonsense.

There must be some combo of  and  or `<distributionManagement> <repository> <id>central</id> <name> <url>https://localhost/artifactory/...`   that makes this work. What am I missing?

pom.xml snippet:

```
    <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>LocalMac-releases</name>
        <url>https://localhost/artifactory/TBX</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>LocalMac-snapshots</name>
        <url>https://localhost/artifactory/TBX</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Master settings.xml snippet: localRepository is commented out so it takes the default. When commented in whatever I enter does take effect... combined with ${user.home}.

```
<!-- localRepository
   | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
   |
   | Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository
  <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>
-->
```

Comment: Can you show what you have configurate in distributionManagement and in your settings (without passwords/username)...

Comment: Well, it looks like I need more pieces and parts. artifactory-maven-plugin (seemed to go in OK) and maven-antrun-plugin (not working yet).